# Split by percentage

Tags: r

I would like to know how to split a vector by a percentage. I tried to use the stats :: quantile function but it doesn't manage to separate correctly when there are several times the same values.
I would like a method that does the split only by taking into account the length of the vector without taking into account the values.

```
vector  <- c(1,1,1, 4:10) 
minProb <- 0.1
maxProb <- 0.9

l   <- length(vector)
dt  <- data.frame("id" = 1:l, "value" = vector)
dt  <- dt %>% arrange(act) 
#min <- l*minProb
#max <- l*maxProb
#data1 <- dt$id[min:max]
#data2 <- dt$id[-c(min:max)]
#q <- quantile(dt$act, probs=c(minProb,maxProb))
#w <- which(dt$act >= q[1] & dt$act <= q[2])
```

## expected result (index of elements)

```
> g2 
1 10
> g1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: hello, excuse me for the lack of information. I edited my post for add the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does split the vector, whether that's what the question asks for is not clear.

```
l <- length(vector)
qq <- quantile(seq_along(vector), probs = c(minProb, maxProb))
f <- logical(l)
f[round(qq[1])] <- TRUE
f[round(qq[2])] <- TRUE
split(vector, cumsum(f))
#$`0`
#[1] 1
#
#$`1`
#[1] 1 1 4 5 6 7 8
#
#$`2`
#[1]  9 10
```

In order to have the indices, like it is asked in a comment, do

```
split(seq_along(vector), cumsum(f))
```

Comment: You could also do `split(vector, cut(seq_along(vector), breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(seq_along(vector), probs = c(minProb, maxProb)), Inf)))`

Comment: Hello,
Instead of having the values ​​I would like to have the indexes

Comment: @Rui Barradas with your method we have 1, 9 and 10 which are taken (it must come from the fact that you make a rounding) whereas with the method of akrun we only have 1 and 10. Is there a way to recover akrun's method but to return the indexes? If not your method responds well to what I wanted

Comment: @problème0123 Use the same trick, `split(seq_along(vector), etc)`.